# Find missing number in sorted array

Tags: binary-search

Whats wrong with this code ? Not able able to search missing number in a consecutive array using binary search.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]

lent = len(a)
beg =0
end = lent-1

while beg < end:
    mid = (beg + end) / 2
    if (a[mid]-a[beg])==(mid - beg):
        beg = mid + 1
    else:
        end = mid -1
    if(beg == end):
        mid = (beg + end) / 2
        print "missing"
        print a[0]+ beg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #1**: Yes, there was another one mistake. You're right. Here's updated version

Try this variant:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]

lent = len(a)
beg =0
end = lent-1

while beg < end:
    mid = (beg + end) / 2
    if (a[mid]-a[beg])==(mid - beg):
        beg = mid
    else:
        end = mid
    if abs(beg-end) <= 1:
        print "missing: %s" % (a[0] + max(beg, mid),)
```

Result:

```
missing: 6
```

Also, try use functions, so you could easily test and debug your code on different lists:

```
def find_missing(a):
    lent = len(a)
    beg =0
    end = lent-1

    while beg < end:
        mid = (beg + end) / 2
        if (a[mid]-a[beg])==(mid - beg):
            beg = mid
        else:
            end = mid
        if abs(beg-end) <= 1:
            return a[0] + max(beg, mid)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
print find_missing(a)

a = [1,3,4,5,6]
print find_missing(a)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
print find_missing(a)
```

Result:

```
6
2
6
```

Comment: not working for a = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10] . result should still be 6 but giving 9.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Fixed. It's because, usually we use binary search to find existing element :)

Answer (score 0):

//Implementation of the algorithm using java.

```
static int missingNumber(int [] nums) {
    int i=0;
    while(i < nums.length) {
        int correct = nums[i];
        if (nums[i] < nums.length && nums[i] != nums[correct]) {
            swap(nums, i, correct);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        }

    for( int index=0; index<nums.length; index++){
        if(index != nums[index]) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
}
static void swap(int[] nums, int first, int second) {
    int temp = nums[first];
    nums[first] = nums[second];
    nums[second] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission Ravi. In general I would highly encourage inline comments for any code block, but particularly for code blocks that are shared with others. This submission would be much easier to follow and debug if in english explanations for what you intended were on each of the critical lines, i.e. method signatures or conditionals.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
int findMiss(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low>high)
        return -1;

     if(arr[low]-1 != low)
         return arr[low]-1;

     int mid = (low + high) / 2;
     if(arr[mid]-1 != mid)
         return findMiss(arr,low,mid);
     else
         return findMiss(arr,mid+1,high); 
}
```

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev: Find first missing number from sorted array. Calculate first mid position from array and compare int element at mid position with mid index. If element-1 at mid position not equal to mid it means we need to traverse to left side of mid (i.e. from 0th position to mid) else traverse right side of mid (i.e. from mid position to end position).