# How to find a missing number in a sorted list with O(log n) time complexity?

Tags: python

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

def findMissingNumber(A):
    n = len(A)

    for i in range(1, n):
        if (A[i - 1] != i):
            return i
    return n

print(findMissingNumber(A))
```

Comment: Use a divide and conquer algorithm.

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that you can tell whether a number is missing in asequence by comparing the difference between the first and last numbers to the length of the sequence.

Comment: Are the numbers always expected to increment by 1 each time? Will it always start at 1? i.e. might you see `[5,10,20,25,30]`  (where 15 is missing?)

Comment: @match Since the linear algorithm assumes it's by 1, I think it's safe to say that the logN algorithm should be the same.

Comment: @match yes, always incremented by 1 each time but it is not started at 1

Comment: @Barmar how to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find missing number in sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386959/find-missing-number-in-sorted-array). The accepted answer is O(log n)

Comment: @RyanBa I don't give the answers to homework problems, I just point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result in O(log N), you can create a recursive function that will check if the middle item is offset from the first one by the same distance as its index.   If it matches, then any missing item would be in the rest of the list (after the middle).  If it doesn't match, then the missing item is before the middle.  Do this recursively until the mismatch is at position 1.  Then you know that the missing item is the first item + 1.

```
def findMissing(A):
    if len(A)<2: return None          # nothing missing if one or no items
    mid      = len(A)//2              # will check middle item
    expected = A[0]+mid               # should be offset from first one
    actual   = A[mid]                 # what it actually is
    if expected == actual:            # if matches, 
        return findMissing(A[mid:])   #    check rest of list
    if mid > 1:                       # if not,
        return findMissing(A[:mid+1]) #    missing is before middle
    return A[0]+1                     # or found missing item

A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
print(findMissing(A))
```

*This process will eliminate half the list from the search at each recursion thus finding the missing item in O(log N) time.*

Comment: @Alian T. Thanks very much